# How to get every number in an ArrayList into a variable

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, processing

So, I'm creating a game, and when the user's player hits a location(There are many), I want it to be game over.

I have two `ArrayLists` like this.

```
ArrayList<Integer> ex = new ArrayList<Integer>(), ey = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And the 'bad' square (which the user dies if they hit it) appear after they've gotten a powerup, so there are `Integers` added on often.

I've trying to do a `for loop` to loop through the size(shown below), but that doesn't work as `i` only selects the latest one, obviously.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ex.size() - 1; i++) {
            if(x.get(0)==ex.get(i) && y.get(0) == ey.get(i)){
                gameover = true;
            }
        }
```

If I just loop through the whole `arrayList` like this

```
(int i : ex)
```

Then it gives me this(below) error upon starting the game:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at snakegame.SnakeGame.draw(SnakeGame.java:113)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So, is there anyway to store all the numbers of the ArrayList in one variable?

Comment: Did you test the array list size before looping through it? If you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException, the list may be empty. Try a System.out.print(ex.size()) ; before the for loop.

Comment: You should provide some more detail. What is `x`, what is `y`? What do `ex` and `ey` store? `for (Object o : ArrayList<Object>) is the proper way to use an iterator to loop through an ArrayList.

Comment: @DavidJones, x & y store the position of the character, ex and ey store the position of the enemy position

Comment: rather than storing two ArrayLists which can get out of sync with each other, I'd strongly recommend encapsulating x,y coordinates in a single Class such as a `Coordinate(x,y)` or using an existing `Point` class. Then you can have an `ArrayList<Coordinate>`. Also, when looping `i < x.size()-1` will miss out on the last item in the list (in case that isn't intended)

Comment: Ah yes, that is true, I will do that soon, thankyou! I'm not as organised as I should be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused with the semantics of the "enhanced for"

```
for(int i = 0; i < ex.size() - 1; i++) {
```

puts into `i` the values `0`, `1`, `2`... up to `ex.size()-1`. `i` works as the **index**

```
for(int i : ex) {
```

puts into `i` the values `ex.get(0)`, `ex.get(1)`. It is the **content**.

In the second case, the logic should be

```
int j = 0;
for (int i : ex) {
  if(x.get(0) == i && y.get(0) == ey.get(j)){
    ..
  }
  j++;
}
```

In this case the enhanced for makes little sense.

If it helps you visualize, thing that with enhanced for, the variable must be always of the type of the array / iterator (in this case, it just happens that you can autooutbox `Integer` to `int`)

Comment: Wooh, thanks alot man! Worked like a charm, I've never seen this used before, so I'm glad I learned something.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you have an x,y grid in which there are coordinates that cause the user to die. As your user moves through the grid, you want to check whether or not the square they're currently on is a bad square.

Instead of two ArrayLists, it might be better to store it as a [multidimensional array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

```
class Grid {

    private int[][] spaces;

    public Grid(int xdim, int ydim) {
        spaces = new int[xdim][ydim];
        for (int x=0; x<xdim; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<ydim; y++) {
                spaces[x][y] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void addBadSpace(int x, int y) {
        spaces[x][y] = 999;
    }

    private boolean isBadSpace(int x, int y) {
        return (spaces[x][y] != 0);
    }

}
```

Whether you take this approach depends on the size of your application and your grid. The multidimensional array will be very quick, but will take up a lot of space in memory. If it's a sparse matrix (i.e. very few 'bad' spaces exist) and your grid is very large, there are more efficient approaches.

Comment: This is actually a very good idea,I will for sure add this and try it out myself! Thanks for adding this.